# can not delete folders from user managed notebooks in Vertex AI, shows Delete Failed, Directory /home/jupyter not empty

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

In Vertex AI workbench, User managed notebooks. I am unable to delete a folder that are not empty even if it contains an empty folder inside. A pop up will appear showing ***Delete Failed*** and directory `/home/jupyter/...` is not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two solutions to this question that I found out.

1. Delete from the last file inside in the folder towards the parent folder, then you can delete it.
2. open terminal from the launcher by clicking on the **+** symbol and then

navigate to the home by entering this command `cd $BASE/../..` then list the contents by `ls` and then
`rm -r directory_name`
replace directory_name with folder or file you want to delete.

this way you can delete the folders or files.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference in UmN `/home/jupyter/` and default subfolders should not be deleted it contains system information for JupyterLab to operate,